# How can I animate my view resizing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uianimation

I am resizing my tables headerView. I want to animate it, but I am not sure how.

```
-(void)layoutForBanner
{
    // Depending on if the banner has been loaded, we adjust the content frame and banner location
    // to accomodate the ad being on or off screen.
    // This layout is for an ad at the bottom of the view.
    if(banner.bannerLoaded)
    {
        headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 94);
    }
    else
    {
        headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
    }   

    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:headerView];

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.5];
    headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```